# Send query from bot framework emulator to teams and getting reply from teams to bot framework emulator

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

- I want to connect my bot emulator to teams for sending a query(This is working)
- Once we receive a query in teams, answer to the query should be sent back to bot emulator

I'm not receiving answer from teams to bot emulator

Comment: In order to facilitate others to help I recommend you explain what you have tried and share the code or the configuration you are using.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you're trying to do exactly? There might not be a need to connect the emulator and Teams directly. Personally, I don't find I make much use of the emulator for a Teams-only bot - just use the Teams client directly to send / receive messages from your bot

Answer (score 0):

To connect from web chat to teams I'm using below code :

```
string teamsChannelId = "****************************";
string serviceUrl = "****************************";
string botClientID = "****************************";
string botClientSecret = "****************************";
MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(serviceUrl);
var connectorClient = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(serviceUrl), new MicrosoftAppCredentials(botClientID, botClientSecret));
var topLevelMessageActivity = MessageFactory.Text(saveconv);
var conversationParameters = new ConversationParameters
{
    IsGroup = true,
    ChannelData = new TeamsChannelData
    {
        Channel = new ChannelInfo(teamsChannelId),
    },
    Activity = topLevelMessageActivity
};
await connectorClient.Conversations.CreateConversationAsync(conversationParameters);
```

---

To send response from Microsoft teams to web chatbot below code worked:

```
var userAccount = new ChannelAccount(id: "userid", name: "username", role: "user", aadObjectId: null);
var botAccount = new ChannelAccount(id: "botid", name: "botname", role: "bot", aadObjectId: null);
string botClientID = "****************************";
string botClientSecret = "****************************";
string serviceUrl = "****************************";
MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(serviceUrl);
var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(serviceUrl), new MicrosoftAppCredentials(botClientID, botClientSecret));
IMessageActivity message = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
message.ChannelId = "channelid";
message.From = botAccount;
message.Recipient = userAccount;
message.Conversation = new ConversationAccount(id: "conversationid");
message.Text = "Reply from Microsoft Teams: *" + turnContext.Activity.Text;
message.Locale = "en-us";
await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync((Activity)message);
```